# Access docker-machine containers from external network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-machine

I have setup a docker-machine with 3 docker containers on my mac (server). Now I have setup third network-adapter in bridged mode, on my virtualbox instance. I can access my docker instances in the internal network now, without problems.
If also setup a port forwarding on my router, but I can't reach my docker instances from there any ideas?

This is how the structure looks like:

Internet --> Router (External-IP:80 -> Docker-Host-IP:80) -> Mac -> Virutalbox -> Docker Webserver

Comment: External network is the network in which your Mac is in, or one "layer" above (public internet?) ?

Comment: Layer above, public internet